# Possible to get a warning for use of conditional null operator with extension method that accepts null reference?

Tags: c#, .net, resharper

Example code in project targeting `net5.0`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

#nullable enable

NullPropagationWithExtensionMethodExperiment(null);

static void NullPropagationWithExtensionMethodExperiment(IEnumerable<int>? integers)
{
    var result = integers?.SumIntegers(); // null-coalesce should be warned of here IMO
    Console.WriteLine(result?.Sum);
}

public record Result(int Sum);

public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static Result SumIntegers(this IEnumerable<int>? integers) => new(integers?.Sum() ?? 42);
}
```

As written, this will output a blank line to the console because the call to the `SumIntegers` extension method is bypassed by the conditional null operator on the line with the comment. If that `?.` is replaced by a regular `.` then `SumIntegers` is called and the value of 42 is returned and output.

No warning is given by default in either case, but I would very much like to find a way of having one appear for the code with the conditional null operator present. If an extension method accepts a null and potentially has specific handling for that case, then I really want to know if it's been bypassed.

I've looked through the Roslyn code analysis rules and in ReSharper's code inspections but couldn't find a suitable check, but it's quite possible I missed it among the many available options -- does anyone know if one exists, or if there's any other way to generate a warning for this situation?

(Edited example to shorten via use of top-level statements)

Comment: Why do you need a warning? It's perfectly valid code to use the null conditional operator when calling extension methods.

Comment: @DavidG the OP's point is that extension method has `this` parameter marked as nullable, so it accepts and handles nulls. OP doesn't want to skip extension method invocation in this case.

Comment: Exactly as @Evk says

Comment: @Evk I know that, but my point is that a code analyser doesn't have any way to distinguish between a "valid" call and an "invalid" one since it's perfectly reasonable code to write.

Comment: If this is nullable-aware code and the ext method takes a nullable reference type then using `?.` on it deserves a warning in my view. The case in which you'd actually want that call elided is very hard to imagine. In code without `#nullable enable` then it's less clear-cut perhaps, but think it's still arguable. If the warning was there we could at least make a choice and configure it to taste.

Comment: Yes, but remember it's just syntactic sugar for a null check like this: `if(integers != null) { MyExtensions.SumIntegers(integers); }`, hence why there is no warning.

Comment: I'm aware, but I'd contend that your case there should also be warned of, at least by ReSharper if not Roslyn. R# gives plenty of squiggles for other things that are not much different in relevance or impact to this.

Comment: But regardless, my question stands, I'd like the warning. If anyone can point me to an existing way of obtaining one other than writing my own analyser, I'd be most grateful.